# AngularJS ng-click not working inside directive dynamic template function

Tags: angularjs, templates, compilation, directive, angularjs-ng-click

I created an Angularjs directory for an inline editor. The HTML template is created by using function and compiling with the HTML root element. My problem is I want to change a status variable when I click on an element to achieve toggling, but it seems not to be working.

I've included the code snippets for reference, which is written inside a directive link function.

```
var appendTotemplate = function () {
            var uploadMediaName = "hello";
            var MediaNameEditable = false;

            template = "<a ng-if='MediaNameEditable !=true' ng-click='MediaNameEditable=true'" + uploadMediaName + "</a>" +
                            "<input ng-if='MediaNameEditable==true' type='text' value='" + uploadMediaName + "' id='mediatxt' ng-click='MediaNameEditable=false;' >";
            var linkFn = $compile(template);
            var content = linkFn(scope);
            element.append(content);

        }();
```

Please check the code. I really want to implement this way. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The var MediaNameEditable should be attached to scope. Try this

```js
var appendTotemplate = function () {
            var uploadMediaName = "hello";
            scope.MediaNameEditable = false;

            template = "<a ng-if='MediaNameEditable !=true' ng-click='MediaNameEditable=true'" + uploadMediaName + "</a>" +
                            "<input ng-if='MediaNameEditable==true' type='text' value='" + uploadMediaName + "' id='mediatxt' ng-click='MediaNameEditable=false;' >";
            var linkFn = $compile(template);
            var content = linkFn(scope);
            element.append(content);

        }();
```

or you can make a function to toggle the `MediaNameEditable`

```js
var appendTotemplate = function () {
            var uploadMediaName = "hello";
            scope.MediaNameEditable = false;

            scope.toggleMediaName = function(isEditable)
            {
              scope.MediaNameEditable = isEditable;
            }

            template = "<a ng-if='MediaNameEditable !=true' ng-click='toggleMediaName(true)'" + uploadMediaName + "</a>" +
                            "<input ng-if='MediaNameEditable==true' type='text' value='" + uploadMediaName + "' id='mediatxt' ng-click='toggleMediaName(false)' >";
            var linkFn = $compile(template);
            var content = linkFn(scope);
            element.append(content);

        }();
```

Comment: Hey is there any  ways to access scope variable inside that template? I want to change that local variables(uploadMediaName ,MediaNameEditable ) and take it from the directive scope . I tried something but it doesn't seems to be working inside the template. But I'm getting the value I checked by using alert dialog.

Comment: Bind it to scope as well and use in template scope.uploadMediaName = "hello". This is so because when you compile, you do it with scope (linkFn(scope), so while compiling it tries to find variables used in template if they exist on the scope.

Comment: ys.I bind with the scope variable. alert is working fine  inside the template function but when I attach the value to a html label it isn't displaying the data.

Comment: Simulate your case in any of online editors so we can check